# Xamarin Android Twilio Voice Binding Project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, twilio

I am currently trying to implement VOIP on Xamarin using the current Twilio .aar file (voice-android-2.0.0-beta13.aar). Currently I am having a lot of trouble trying to get this to work. I have linked both relinker-1.2.2.aar, ion-2.1.8.aar and androidasync-2.1.8.aar within this project as Twilio depends on them.

The errors which I am getting range from

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0030  Cannot convert type 'Com.Twilio.Voice.Call' to 'Java.Lang.Object'   Twilio.Droid.Binding    

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0102  The type 'ErrorEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'P0'    Twilio.Droid.Binding    

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0115  'Call.SendDigits(string)': no suitable method found to override Twilio.Droid.Binding
```

Currently I have tried to change the Metadata.xml file to handle these errors however there is little documentation and even when including paths generated from the C# code, I get that the entries matches no nodes.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You should review Jon Douglas' Xamarin Android Bindings Troubleshooting Guide (https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb) and than post a specific question concerning node matching for your metadata problem(s).

Comment: Any luck implementing this? I am stuck binding version 2.0.1

Comment: Hi @JustAGuy,  have you managed to implement this. I have to implement the same. Did you able to have voice calls.